# Less CSS: & reverse parent with multiple classes?

Tags: less

This is the first time I'm finding the & parent selector extremely useful so that I don't need to redefine parents simply to modify a child element.

Of course this is actually easy with LESS, but I have to ask!

```
<div id="skrollr-body" class="nonav">
    <div class="skrollable">

    </div>
</div>


#skroller-body {
    .skrollable {
        margin-top:40px;

        .nonav & {
            // this parent selector lets me modify 
            // .skrollable without duplicating it
            margin-top:0px;

        }
    }
}
```

The output of `.nonav &` is 
`.nonav #skroller-body .skrollable`

I'm wondering if I can get `#skroller-body.nonav .skrollable` instead somehow without extra HTML markup (a wrapper `div.nonav`)?

Currently I'll just duplicate the parent

```
#skrollr-body {
    margin-top:40px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;

    .skrollable {
        margin-top:40px;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:100;
        .skrollable {
            position:absolute;

            .skrollable {
                position:static;
            }
        }
    }
    &.nonav {
            .skrollable {
                 margin-top:0px;
            }
    }
}
```

Or to save redundant output;

`#skroller-body.nonav .scrollable { margin-top:0px; }`

But the whole point here is CSS code that's *easy to maintain and read*.

Answer (score 5):

[The docs tell us:](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature)

> The `&` operator represents the parent selectors of a nested rule and
>   is most commonly used when applying a modifying class or pseudo-class
>   to an existing selector

So:

```
#skroller-body {
        &.nonav {
            .skrollable {
                // stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a good point I don't need to duplicate the parent content!